# Binary optimization

Tags: matrices, optimization, integer-programming

Let me first make my background clear. I am a PhD student with not much knowledge in optimization but I need to do some optimization as a part of my research work. My problem is as follows:

There are two matrices `P` and `N` (both have variable rows and `n` columns). I have to maximize the sum of minimal Hausdorff distance between $AP$ and $N$. $A$ is a binary vector $[0,1]$ and $||A||_1$ lies between a `user specified range`. In short, $A$ is a vector which selects points from $P$ - let's say that point set is $p$ - such that if you add `maximal Hausdorff distance(p,N)` for each $p$ then it will be at its maximum. (So if you take any other point set $p$ and do the same procedure, the sum should be always less than the point set specified by $A$).

Now at the same time, I have to minimize the sum of minimal Hausdorff distances with $AP$ and $P$. In short, if a points in $P$ are in the form of a circle, then $A$ should pick the point which lies on the center of the circle.

Now, if we consider a trivial case when you want to pick only one point, then we can just exhaustively search which point satisfies the following two conditions (Also, point is always selected from P):

1. Sum of distances of that point to every point in N should be maximized.
2. Sum of distances of that point to every point in P should be minimized.

Is there a way to achieve this? I should mention a few more things. I am unaware of optimization limitations, for example, I have heard that its very difficult to get a binary vector, so in above example, I will get `A` whose values are real. That is totally fine. Just let me know if there are any other constraints and if this problem is at all possible. I can add a small example if necessary. Also, I am not looking for answer but a direction to my efforts, maybe formulate this into an equation and tell me the approach.

Comment: "$A$ is a vector which selects points from $P$": Let me make sure I'm understanding you correctly. Where you write $AP$, you don't really mean the matrix-vector product of $A$ and $P$ but rather the subset of the rows of $P$ corresponding to the nonzero entries in $A$, right? And then you treat them as a set of $n$-dimensional vectors and try to maximize the function $\sum_{p\in AP} \min_{n\in N} d(p,n)$?

Comment: @ℝⁿ - Yes you are correct. But let me clarify my doubt too. Lets say $P$ is a 2-D point set of 5 points and we know that 2nd point satisfies the condition with $N$ (i.e. Sum of distances of that point to every point in $N$ should be maximized). So `A=[0 1 0 0 0]`, therefore even if you take vector-matrix product, 2nd point will be multiplied with one, everything else becomes zero. Is there anything wrong in considering vector matrix product? Though I will iterate again that whatever you have written is right provided $\min_{n \in N} d(p,n) $ denotes minimal Hausdorff distance.

Comment: When only one element of $A$ is $1$ then everything is fine. But when $A=[0,1,0,0,1]$ for example then $AP=p_2+p_5$, that is, you don't get the points $p_2$ and $p_5$ separately, you only get their sum. // Also I don't know what you mean by "minimal Hausdorff distance" and "maximal Hausdorff distance". There is only [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance).

Comment: @ ℝⁿ - You are right that $AP$ cannot be a vector-matrix product. Let me now come to minimum Hausdorff distance. It is also sometimes called "modified Haussdorff distance". It is defined as $h(A,B)$=$\min_{a \in A}$ $\min_{b \in B }$ $d(A,B)$. It can be found in the paper, "Solving multiple-instance problem: A lazy learning approach.". But now thinking about it again, since we will be taking one point in $p$ at a time, $\min_{n \in N}$ $d(p,n)$ can be reduced to finding a nearest neighbor of $p$ in the set $N$.